# Audio Matching (Audio Fingerprinting)

Tags: android, audio-fingerprinting

I'm writing an android app that lets user record his voice through microphone & save it in storage & link it to a specific content (like a Contact). Later, user call that voice again & the app should compare it with saved audio files & find the one that matches the voice.

I searched a lot & found some libraries that do this online, like [EchoPrint](https://github.com/echonest/EchoprintForAndroid) that generates fingerprint from recorded audio & sends it to opensource server & returns the result. But I need to do this offline.

Has anybody know such library?

Answer (score 7):

If you are aiming to compare an old recording of a user with a new call as it comes in, audio fingerprinting solutions like [Dejavu](http://github.com/worldveil/dejavu) in Python on a server or [Echoprint](https://github.com/echonest/EchoprintForAndroid) in C++ won't help you. They are for doing recognition and retrieval on recorded audio segments plus noise. 
They cannot deal with the variabilites in human voice. See an explanation [here](http://willdrevo.com/fingerprinting-and-audio-recognition-with-python/).

If that's the case, what you are referring to is [speaker recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_recognition), which is much harder and involves quite a bit of machine learning. It would be tough to do this for a large corpus of users (especially offline on a phone), but for determining between a couple users, it might be doable.

Answer (score 1):

Below is  a good Library. Which is Easy to use. But you need to convert your Audio Files to Wave Format prior to this.

https://code.google.com/p/musicg/

Comment: This is not a speaker recognition library